# Area of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

The following problem in elementary geometry was proposed to me. As a mathematical analyst, I confess that I can't solve it. And I have no idea of what I could do. Here it is: pick a triangle, and draw the three *mediana* (i.e. the segments that join a vertex with the midpoint of the opposite side). Use the three segments to construct a second triangle, and prove that the area of this triangle is $3/4$ times the area of the original triangle.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "use the three *segments* "? Shouldn't it be "use the three new vertices" ?

Comment: No: you draw the *segment* that joins a vertex with the opposite midpoint. You get three such segments, and you use them to build a triangle.

Comment: Oh, I see...thanks. How can we be sure such a (n euclidean) triangle is constructible?

Comment: Well, that is part of the problem. But I suspect it is not the hardest part.

Comment: It should be $1/4$ instead of $3/4$.

Comment: @DonAntonio If the area of a triangle with given lengths is positive, then it exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested we can define any triangle with two vectors: $\mathbf{a}=\begin{pmatrix}{a_1 \\a_2} \end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathbf{b} = \mathbf{e}_1$, such that $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are not colinear and where $\mathbf{b}$ has been chosen for simplicity.

Then a linear map, $A$, can be constructed to send these vectors to there corresponding line segments. If we get that the determinant of $A$ is such that $\det{A}=\frac{3}{4}$ the result will be proved.

After drawing a picture of a triangle defined in such a way it is clear that we want the map $A$ such that: 
$$\mathbf{a} \mapsto \mathbf{b} - \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{a}  , $$
$$\mathbf{b} \mapsto \mathbf{a} - \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{b}   .$$

This completely determines $A$ and after solving some equations we get that: $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1-\frac{a_1}{2} & -\frac{1+a_1^2}{2a_2}\\-\frac{a_2}{2} & 1+\frac{a_1}{2} \end{pmatrix}.$$

Upon computing $\det(A)$ we get that it is $\frac{3}{4}$ proving what is required.

Answer (score 6):

I believe there is a nice visual explanation for this.

Start with a triangle and draw its medians.

[image: triangle]

Then construct congruent triangles to form a hexagon, and connect every other vertex on its perimeter.

[image: hexagon]

Let $A=$ (area of the original triangle) and $B=$ (area of the triangle of medians). The shaded triangle has area $4B$, because its sides are twice as long as the medians, and it is also equal to half the area of the hexagon, which is $6A/2=3A$. $3A=4B$, so $B=\frac{3}{4}A$.

Comment: great answer! up-voted.

Comment: This is just awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

Use vectors.It will be really helpful.Define sides of triangle ABC as A=0, B= b vector and C= c vector.

Answer (score 2):

In a triangle $ABC$ with medians intersecting at $O$, draw a line throgh $A$ parallel to the median through $B$ and a line through $B$ parallel to the median through $A$. Let $D$ be the intersection of the new lines. Then the parallelogram $AOBD$ has area $2/3$ of the area of the triangle $ABC$ but it can also be partitioned by the diagonal $OD$ into two triangles made out of intervals of lengths $2/3$ of the lengths of the medians themselves. Hence the area of the triangle formed by the medians is $(3/2)^2$ times $1/3$, or $3/4$ of the area of the triangle $ABC$.

Comment: Instead of "parallel to the side $BC$ (resp. $AC$)", don't you mean "parallel to the median through $B$ (resp. $A$)"?

Comment: @TonyK, Right, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Use the blue triangle]

If you don't understand vector that well then you can use this proof

Assume that three medians BD,AE and CF are p,q,r respectively and the triangle made by the medians is $\triangle {X}$

Now we draw parallelogram $ GCIA $. Area of $ \triangle {GAC}= \frac {1}{3} \triangle {ABC} $ ( As the medians divide a triangle into six congruent triangles. And there is two of them in $ \triangle {GAC} $ ).

Now $\triangle {GAI} = \triangle {GAC} $

$ \triangle {GAC}= \frac {1}{3} \triangle {ABC} $

$ GA= \frac {2}{3} AE = \frac {2}{3} q $
similarly $GI = \frac {2}{3} p$ and $AI= \frac {2}{3}r$

So $\triangle {GAI} $ is triangle whose sides are two third of $\triangle {X}$.

So the area of $\triangle {GAI} = \frac {4}{9} \triangle {X}$

$ \frac {4}{9} \triangle {X} = \frac {1}{3} \triangle {ABC}$

$ \frac {4}{3} \triangle {X} = \triangle {ABC} $

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Let's $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ the vertexs of the original triangle. Its area ${\cal A}$ is given by the magnitude of:
$$
\half\,\vec{a}\times\vec{b} + \half\,\vec{b}\times\vec{c} + \half\,\vec{c}\times\vec{a}
$$ 
Middle points of the triangle are: 
$$
\half\,\pars{\vec{a} + \vec{b}}\,,\ \half\,\pars{\vec{b} + \vec{c}}\ \mbox{and}\ \half\,\pars{\vec{c} + \vec{a}}
$$
The 'new' area is given by:
\begin{align}
&\half\bracks{\half\,\pars{\vec{a} + \vec{b}}\times\half\,\pars{\vec{b} + \vec{c}}}
+
\half\bracks{\half\,\pars{\vec{b} + \vec{c}}\times\half\,\pars{\vec{c} + \vec{a}}}
+
\half\bracks{\half\,\pars{\vec{c} + \vec{a}}\times\half\,\pars{\vec{a} + \vec{b}}}
\\[3mm]&=
{\vec{a}\times\vec{b} + \vec{a}\times\vec{c} + \vec{b}\times\vec{c} \over 8}
+
{\vec{b}\times\vec{c} + \vec{b}\times\vec{a} + \vec{c}\times\vec{a} \over 8}
+
{\vec{c}\times\vec{a} + \vec{c}\times\vec{b} + \vec{a}\times\vec{b} \over 8}
\\[3mm]&={\vec{a}\times\vec{b} + \vec{b}\times\vec{c} + \vec{c}\times\vec{a} \over 8}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\Large{1 \over 4}}\,\pars{{\vec{a}\times\vec{b} + \vec{b}\times\vec{c} + \vec{c}\times\vec{a} \over 2}}
\end{align}

Comment: The new triangle is not the one whose vertices are the midpoints of the old triangle's sides. It shall be a triangle whose sides have the lengths of the three medians.

Comment: @DanielFischer 0 k. I'll checked it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $AA', BB', CC'$ be the medians, and let $G$ be their intersection. Let $G'$ be the symmetric of $G$ with respect to $A'$. Then, since $BGCG'$ is a parallelogram, in the triangle $BGG'$ we have

$$BG=\frac{2}{3}BB' \,;\,  BG'=\frac{2}{3}CC' \,;\, GG'=\frac{2}{3}AA' \,.$$

Thus, area of $BGG'$ is $\frac{4}{9}$ area of the triangle made by the medians.

Also, area $BGG'=\frac{1}{2}$ area $BGCG'$=area $BGC=\frac{1}{3}$ area $ABC$.

[the last equality follows either by repeating the argument by the other two sides, or observing that $ABC$ and $GBC$ have the same base, and their heights are $3:1$].

Thus

$$\mbox{Area} BGG'=\frac{4}{9} \mbox{Area of the median triangle} $$

$$\mbox{Area} BGG'=\frac{1}{3} \mbox{Area} ABC$$

**Simplification** Here is a much simpler version of this proof:

Note the the area of $BGC$ is $\frac{1}{3}$ area of $ABC$.

Now cut  $BGC$ along the side $GA'$ and rotate $CGA'$ by $180^o$ degrees. Then you get a triangle with the sides $\frac{2}{3}$ the medians. Equate the areas.

Answer (score 0):

"Here it is: pick a triangle":

Since we get to pick the triangle, I will pick a triangle **T1** that has equal sides, therefore 3 equal angles = **60 degrees**.  Let's call the sides "**A**".   The area of this triangle **T1** is equal to **[0.5 * A * A]**.  Each of the 3 "medianas" will have a magnitude equal to **[A * Sin(60)]**, therefore a triangle **T2** constructed from these 3 medianas will have an area equal to **(0.5 * [A * Sin(60)] * [A * Sin(60)])**

Dividing the area of Triangle **T2** by the area of triangle **T1**:

Ratio of Areas = **(0.5 * [A * Sin(60)] * [A * Sin(60)])** / **[0.5 * A * A]**

Ratio of Areas = **Sin(60)**  *  **Sin(60)**

Ratio of Areas = **0.75** = **3/4**